# Janusys v4 Schedular and BindingSource/LinQ how to

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, janus

It seems, that Janusys isn't active anymore. The Forum Posts get not answered since a while. In my application (Winforms!), I use there controls since a couple of years. Now I want to extend my application with the schedular Control.
I found a Sample within the Janus Software, where they "explain", how the Control can be used, in DataBound mode.
The Problem there is, that this example works with DataSet / TableAdapter.
This I don't want to use, because I use in my whole application LinQ.
Now, I tried to move on, with there sample application and rewrite it, so I can use LinQ. But I am not able to get it working.

I use BindingSource to bind my data via LinQ from the database to the Control. This works really fine and all saved Appointments get displayed as expected.
But...
I am not getting it working, to create/update Appointments.
1) The BindingSource AddNew Handler is fired, but with "NewObject" is Nothing
2) I don't know, how I get an existing Appointment verified, that this one is already saved in database, or if it is a new Appointment.

Does anyone could help me with this Problem and can explain, how I can do it Right, without using DataSet/TableAdapter?

THX a lot in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THX a lot for everyone, who looked into it.
I found a solution, which looks to work fine.

I have to add all appointments with a ForEach Loop and remove the BindingSource completly.
Then I can add the Key Value, and from there, it is easy, because, I am able to see, if this is already an existing appointment (then the key has a value) or even not.

THX - Have a nice evenenig